# Can someone please explain me how to write an xpath for selenium on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm having trouble clicking on elements in a web page. I'm trying to do this with:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "..........']"))).click()
```

The question is how can I write xpaths correctly in all situations so that they suit this function?

Comment: Please share relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) you can find a good tutorial, which will teach you xPath basics. On the webpage when you press `F12` the dev tools opens:

[image: img]

Then you click on one of the elemnts and then `Ctrl+f`. Then the search menu will open:

[image: img2]

There you can type xPaths and CSS Selectors to make sure, that you have found the right element. For example:

[image: img3]

once you have typed yor xPath , you will see on the right side the number of the elements found, also you can click on `up` and `down` buttons to iterate over every element, to see whic exactly element is on number 1,2...

Once you have found the right xPath, just copy it from dev tools and paste in the code like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div"))).click()
```

In this case it will be selected only one element. If you want to wait until all elements, if there are more than 1, just use one of the `EC` methods, for example:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div")))
```

this will wait for visibility of all elements located by `//div` xPath.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! It was very helpful.

Comment: Could you please also tell me why this line of code gives me a TimeoutException please? (The point is that it works but it also gives me the error and stops the program) WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='AutoNumber1']//a[href='lnkdati.htm']"))).click()

Comment: It is beacause the element wasn't clickable, or it was a wrong element. I don't have HTML to see exactly, but probably you have a typo here => `a[href='lnkdati.htm']` should be `a[href='lnkdati.html']`. Check in dev tools exactly

Comment: My bad.. The problem was that basically I had already done that operation without knowing it and with that line of code I was trying to do it again but I was already on another page. Thank you so much anyway!