# get (int) method undefined for the type list

Tags: java, selenium, get

I am trying to create a selenium script using `get(int)` method undefined for the type list that will select a radio button if it is not selected.

I use the following script:

```
package automationFramework;

import java.awt.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/gradulescu/Documents/Eclipse project/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // Storing the Application Url in the String variable
        String url = "http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/";
        driver.get(url);        
        //Launch the Online Store Website
        List Rbtn = (List) driver.findElement(By.name("sex"));
        boolean bool = false;
        bool =  Rbtn.get(0).isSelected();
        if (bool==true)
        {Rbtn.get(1).click();
            }
        else
        {Rbtn.get(0).click();
            }

    }
}
```

The get method returns the following error:

> method get(int) is undefined for the type list

I use Eclipse 3.8.1 with JConsole 1.8.0_171-b11 and Java VM version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 25.171-b11

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
List Rbtn = (List) driver.findElement(By.name("sex"));
```

with:

```
List<WebElement> rBtn = driver.findElements(By.name("sex")); // this will return a list of all found elements
```

This a sample workable code:

```
driver.get("http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/");

List<WebElement> rBtn = driver.findElements(By.name("sex")); // this will return a list of all found elements
if (rBtn.get(1).isSelected()) // I'm getting the second element because the first one is only label
{   
   rBtn.get(2).click(); //click 'Female'
}
else
{   
   rBtn.get(1).click(); //click 'Male'
}
```

**PS:** always check in dev tools which elements you are locating with your selector. To open dev tools press `F12` in browser. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243354/can-someone-please-explain-me-how-to-write-an-xpath-for-selenium-on-python/51243724#51243724).

Answer (score 0):

As states the doc of [`WebDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-), the `findElements(By by)` method returns a `java.util.List<WebElement>`(*list of object of `WebElement` class*) and not a `java.awt.List` (*list of UI component in awt*).

You need to change your import, and the code to :

```
List<WebElement> rbtn = driver.findElement(By.name("sex"));
```

*note : in Java, variables, parameters, methods names have to sart with a lowercase letter*

Answer (score 0):

`boolean` is false by default so you don't have to explicitly initialize it. Similarly, `if(bool)` will do. Thirdly, you need to use `findElements` when you are storing them in List. Fourth, its a good practice to use `try...catch` block.

Try -

```
package automationFramework;

import java.awt.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/gradulescu/Documents/Eclipse project/geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // Storing the Application Url in the String variable
            String url = "http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/";
            driver.get(url);
            // Launch the Online Store Website
            List<WebElement> Rbtn = driver.findElements(By.name("sex"));
            boolean bool;
            bool = Rbtn.get(0).isSelected();
            if (bool)
                Rbtn.get(1).click();
            else
                Rbtn.get(0).click();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```